# Remove background when edit the node in treeview

Tags: c#, winapi, treeview, treenode

When I edit the treenode (with long name), it has a background color:

[image]

How can I remove the background? How can I change the background color?

I was trying to remove it in OnDrawNode, but it is impossible to do. 
Next, I tried to use the TVM_GETEDITCONTROL message and send WM_CTLCOLOREDIT, but it doesn't work too:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    internal const int WM_CTLCOLOREDIT = 0x0133;
    internal const int TVM_GETEDITCONTROL = 0x110F;

private void NodeTree_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode nodeEditing = e.Node;
        IntPtr editControlHandle = SendMessage(NodeTree.Handle, (uint)TVM_GETEDITCONTROL, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (editControlHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            SendMessage(editControlHandle, (uint)WM_CTLCOLOREDIT, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Red), new IntPtr(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The  WM_CTLCOLOREDIT is sent BY the Edit to it's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This background - the background of the selected node.
In the event BeforeLabelEdit I unsubscribe from AfterSelect, memorize the selected node and deselect nodes:

```
private TreeNode SelectedNodeBeforeEdit;

private void NodeTree_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    NodeTree.AfterSelect -= NodeTree_AfterSelect;
    SelectedNodeBeforeEdit = NodeTree.SelectedNode;
    NodeTree.SelectedNode = null;
}
```

In the event AfterLabelEdit I subscribe to AfterSelect and exhibit the selected node:

```
private void NodeTree_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    NodeTree.SelectedNode = SelectedNodeBeforeEdit;
    NodeTree.AfterSelect += NodeTree_AfterSelect;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of unsubscribing from the _AfterSelect_ event? And why don't you unsubscribe from the _BeforeSelect_ event too?

Comment: @Luca Cremonesi
This is necessary so that the AfterSelect event does not occured when we set SelectedNode (NodeTree.SelectedNode = SelectedNodeBeforeEdit;). I don't unsubscribe from BeforeSelect because I don't use this in my project, but you can do it.